# Problems with importing a JSON tweet into hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, cloudera

i work on cloudera quickstart with docker, I'm trying to create a table into hive interface.
This is my code.

```
add jar hdfs:///user/cloudera/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
drop table if exists tweets;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
id BIGINT,
created_at STRING,
source STRING,
favorited BOOLEAN,
retweeted_status STRUCT<
 text:STRING,
 user1:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,
 retweet_count:INT>,
entities STRUCT<
 urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
 user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
 hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
text STRING,
user1 STRUCT<
 screen_name:STRING,
 name:STRING,
 friends_count:INT,
 followers_count:INT,
 statuses_count:INT,
 verified:BOOLEAN,
 utc_offset:INT,
 time_zone:STRING>,
 in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
 LOCATION '/user/cloudera/';
 load data inpath '/user/cloudera/search.json' into table tweets;
```

when I run "select * from tweets;", I get this error

```
Fetching results ran into the following error(s):
Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=0, operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0, operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='\xf2e\xcc\xb6v\x8eC"\xae^x\x89*\xd6j\xa7', guid='h\xce\xacgmZIP\x8d\xcc\xc0\xe8C\t\x1a\x0c')), orientation=4, maxRows=100): TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0, errorMessage='java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/2015_11_18', sqlState=None, infoMessages=['*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/2015_11_18:25:24', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:366', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationNextRowSet:OperationManager.java:275', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:752', 'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19:invoke::-1', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43', 'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606',
```

Comment: `Not a file: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/2015_11_18'`... Why is it trying to load this?

Comment: `LOCATION '/user/cloudera/';`... Please don't make your whole user folder a Hive table location

Comment: i dont now why it's trying to load this file.

Comment: why i can't use my user folder for my hive toble location .

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your user folder as a Hive table location. A user folder is meant for general file storage, such as that `2015_11_18` directory it's trying to read, not an entire Hive structure.

Do `LOCATION '/user/cloudera/tweets';`, for example instead.

You could also just make a regular managed table if you don't care if things are deleted when you drop the table.